# How can I optimize this PostreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, pyspark

So I wrote the simple query. But I want to optimize it without using subqueries and union, the only option that came to my mind is to use case when construct. But I'm stuck with its implementation because I can't figure out how I can get 2 (or 1) rows with max date with value on flag 1 and total number of adi for max month.

Structure

```
id 12345678
date 2023-01-01
flag_1 1/0
flag_2 1/0
```

My current script

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT 
    count(id) as ctn_id
    ,max(date) date
    from table.a
    where date = (select max(date) from table.a where flag_1 = 1 )
UNION    
SELECT 
    count(id) as cnt_id
    ,max(date)
    from table.b
    where date = (select max(date) from table.a where flag_2 = 1 )      
""").show(10,0)
```

Comment: Most likely you want `UNION ALL`. Just how to you distinct the results from this query, how do you see the difference between flag_1 and flag_2 ? For performance issues we need the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for this query, in plain text. And also the DDL for the tables and indexes involved.

Comment: Why do you "want to optimize it without using subqueries and union"? What if "using subqueries and union" is the best way to optimize? One shouldn't eliminate any option with good cause.

Comment: Please see [mre]. Sample data and the corresponding expected output are very important if you want others to clearly understand your objectives. If my assumptions regarding the expected results are correct, then it is possible to achieve them without using `UNION`; however, a subquery cannot be avoided.

Comment: Expanding on the comment by @Bohemian: do you want to optimize the query or play games by imposing arbitrary restrictions on which tools are at your disposal? Constraints on permitted approaches may be reasonable for classroom exercises, interview questions, and puzzle contests; however, when solving real-world problems, one should be open to employing any practical means of achieving resolution.